# how to awake device in Doze mode : Doze mode with FCM test case

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.1-nougat

I'm getting stuck on my project based on real time location tracking and update to the server.
Here i tested OS status in doze mode implementing FCM Push notification..

I used two methods to test:

1. Push Notification after device entering in Doze mode(Deep Sleep) :
   When server send push notification to device during Deep sleep mode then
   Android OS Open their Internet service for a moment and again go back to
   previous mode..
   During that short period we can't able to update real time tracking to
   the server(some time may update to server but maximum failure case)
2. Push Notification before Doze mode(Deep Sleep) : Push notification
   working fine but it don't affect the original deep sleep time and again
   Android OS entering in Deep sleep mode without extending Doze mode time
   interval.
   So again we failed to track real time location update to server.

Note: Push notification can not change the Android OS status . Only OS
allows FCM for a moment and again it goes back to deep sleep mode.

Is any alternate solution to continuously track and update to the server?

Comment: I´m stuck with the same issue. Maybe this help you: https://developer.zebra.com/community/android/android-forums/android-blogs/blog/2017/05/04/keeping-your-application-running-when-the-device-wants-to-sleep